# Plotting a 3D surface map with the colour bar representing another quantity

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

Suppose I have a 2D array `Z` which represents the 'height' of a (rectangular) domain, and another 2D array `T` which represents some other quantities (e.g. temperature) in the same spatial domain. I know how to plot the 3D surface plot of `Z` using the `plot_surface` as shown in the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html). However, the colourmap shows the quantity I'm plotting (i.e. the height `Z`). How can I plot the 3D height map of `Z` with the colour bar representing the quantity `T` instead? Since I can already visualize the 3D surface of the height map without the colourbar, I want to reserve the colour display the values of `T` instead.

Comment: Similar questions exists already with adequate answers. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: MATLAB is not python. Matplotlib is not MATLAB. If you have a python question, don't tag it with MATLAB.